# Spring scope references as enums?

Tags: java, spring, scope

Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't there any class that provides `Scope.PROTOTYPE, Scope.SINGLETON` static references?

Or do I always have to use non-typesafe strings as scopes?

```
@Scope("prototype")
@Scope("singleton")
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the [Scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html)'s documentation, the `value` element is of type `String`, not some enum constant. Hence we're searching for a class, where the possible values for the `value` element are exposed.

[BeanDefinition](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html) is the class you're looking for. It provides several `public static String` fields, but you might be interested in these two:

```
SCOPE_SINGLETON
SCOPE_PROTOTYPE
```

And for example, they can be used like:

```
@Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
```

I would advice for re-using them, instead of setting Strings literals all the time, as you might do some typo.

Answer (score 16):

Constants that you can use to avoid literal Strings are:

```
ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON 
ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE
WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST
WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION
```

source: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html

Comment: This should have been marked as the answer.

Comment: agreed, its more informative and also referred with spring javadocs